# jsp jstl sql strange behaviour with as in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, stored-procedures, jstl

In mysql i m having a stored procedure which has a sql like:

```
select firstname as i_firstname , lastname as i_lastname from roleuser 
where user_id = uid ;
```

I m using a jstl code to get the values: -

```
<sql:query var="comm_codes" dataSource="jdbc/myDatasource">
    call sp_select_username(?);
    <sql:param>${user_id}</sql:param>
</sql:query>

<c:forEach var="rows" items="${comm_codes.rows}">
    ${rows.i_firstname} ${rows.i_lastname}
</c:forEach>
```

But this code does not return anything but when the replace the above code **${rows.i_firstname}** with **${rows.firstname}** i get the correct values.

Anything wrong with jstl, is this replicable or my fault here...

Question also posted [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?46,407754,407754#msg-407754) and [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/527329/JSP/java/jsp-jstl-sql-strange-behaviour)

thanks

Comment: What happens when you do this? `<c:forEach var="columnName" items="${comm_codes.columnNames}">
  <c:out value="${columnName}"/>
</c:forEach>`

Comment: firstname lastname (the aliases are not there...)

Comment: Can you for the sake of testing just invoke sql directly instead of from a stored proc? Just try pytting the sql in the sql tag.

Comment: Alright sounds like some strange bug. What versions of mysql, jdbc driver, tomcat are you using? We can do a JIRA search to see if there is any known bug with sql aliases.

Comment: mysql 5.1.44, jstl1.1, glassfish 3.0, jdbc mysql connector 5.1.12

Answer (score 4):

I know it is an old post, but I encountered this problem as well. It is discussed here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,432843,432862#msg-432862

Importantly, the poster in the mysql forum states

> ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName() will return the actual name of the column, **if it exists**

This provides a work-around - prevent the column name from existing, so that the alias must be used.  As an example, the original poster's stored procedure could be modified to be

```
select concat(first name,'') as i_firstname , 
       concat(lastname,'') as i_lastname from roleuser 
where user_id = uid ;
```

In this case, the original column is now unknown, and the alias is used.  I've tested this on my system in a similar situation at it worked.  Likewise, if you need to use an alias for an int, you can try SELECT (id+0) AS id_alias.  I'm sure most column types  have similar solutions.  Hope this helps.