# SQL Query Column Names and JSP/JSTL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jstl

I have a SQL query that I am running using JSTL and JSP in Netbeans..

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="disc">
    select DISCHARGE_STATUS as status, (count(*)/(select count(*) from hw))*100 as result from hw where age=<%= age_group %> and sex=<%= gender %> and ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE=<%= admission_code %>  group by DISCHARGE_STATUS;
</sql:query>
```

and trying to output it with this:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <th>Discharge Status: </th>

    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${disc.rows}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${row.status}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${row.result}"/></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The result gets outputted correctly for result, but the status is blank.

When i runt this query on my php code for a tes, i get the followingt:

```
status result   
a      0.4062   
b      0.0677
```

Comment: What column name?  It's just a percentage, and you haven't assigned it a column name.

Comment: @davidwallace I went ahead and modified the code above

Comment: Umm, try calling it something other than `status`.  I think that's a keyword in JSTL forEach loops.

Comment: @AndyP try some other alias name for status, coz status is keyword

Answer (score 0):

The following link has answer
It is not a apt solution but it works

[jsp jstl sql strange behaviour with as in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998749/jsp-jstl-sql-strange-behaviour-with-as-in-mysql)

select **concat(DISCHARGE_STATUS)** as status, (count(*)/(select count(*) from hw))*100 as result from hw where age=<%= age_group %> and sex=<%= gender %> and ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE=<%= admission_code %>  group by DISCHARGE_STATUS;